# How to sort a container of std::shared_ptr<Widget> objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

```
class Widget;

std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Widget> > container

class Criterium
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Widget& left, const Widget& right)const;
};
```

How can I sort the container according to the Criterium, **without** defining another criterium like:

```
class CriteriumForPointers
{
public:
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& left, 
                    const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& right)const;
};
```

Comment: I mean, is there some C++11 magic I can use? Define some function object on the run, just before the std::sort command, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a lambda as an adapter:

```
Criterium criterium;
sort(container.begin(), container.end(),
     [&criterium] (const shared_ptr<Widget> &l, const shared_ptr<Widget> &r)
     {
         return criterium(*l.get(), *r.get());
     }
);
```

Comment: Cool! That is what I was looking for, but was not smart enough to invent myself!

Comment: Use const references to shared pointers in this case, you are making unnecessary copies/synchronizations.

Comment: @Klaim: Obvious in retrospect, don't know why I missed that. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 4):

Use indirect iterators like this:

```
std::sort(
  boost::make_indirect_iterator(container.begin()),
  boost::make_indirect_iterator(container.end()),
  Criterium()
);
```

See also: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put a second overload of the operator() into your Criterium-classe, like this:

```
class Criterium {
  bool operator()(const Widget& left, const Widget& right)const;
  bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& left,
                  const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& right)const
  { return operator()( *left, *right ); }
};
```

(note: I didn't test this)